# 3rd party jars outside of ear to be accessed from classes inside the ear

Tags: java, jar, ejb, ear

I want to use a 3rd party jar in my application. But its too huge in size. So i want to access it without embedding it in the .ear file. How can i access 3rd party jars outside of ear from classes inside the ear.

I have tried to add the jar files to the lib folder on the server where its deployed. But its not working. Also in clustered environment i will have to keep copies of it on each server.

How can i avoid this. Can i somehow remotely access the 3rd party jar.

3rd party jars outside of ear to be accessed from classes inside the ear

Comment: add that jar to the classpath

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shared library in your EE server console, specifying the directory where these jar files are located.

Then, don't forget to bind this shared library to your application, so the classes from these jars could be loaded by your application classloader. There could be a flag like "use an isolated classloader for library", so you can use that option as well.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of this behaviour is not defined by current Java EE specifications. However, most vendors will provide some way of adding client libraries such as this.

Therefore, you need to look to your vendor's documentation to accomplish this.